# LuaJ and Android: cannot bind class

Tags: java, android, eclipse, lua, libgdx

I am currently writing a game engine in Java using the LibGDX framework. For several months now, I have successfully used LuaJ 3.0 with my engine. I have had no problems getting scripts to run on Android (tested on two devices) or Desktop (in and out of Eclipse).

However, when I tried to deploy to Android today, I got the following error:

```
org.luaj.vm2.LuaError: script:2 vm error: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.javamon.console.ScriptPlayerCreate
```

The line of the script causing this error is:

```
Result = luajava.bindClass("com.javamon.console.ScriptPlayerCreate")
```

This is typographically identical to the class supposedly "not found" on Android.

If I try to bind a regular java class, such as `java.lang.ClassNotFoundException`, I don't get any error. However, **this error does not occur on the Desktop version**, whether run from within Eclipse or via a runnable *.jar.

Here is the stack trace, retrieved from LogCat:

```
org.luaj.vm2.LuaError: script:2 vm error: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.javamon.console.ScriptPlayerCreate
  at org.luaj.vm2.lib.jse.LuajavaLib.invoke(Unknown Source)
  at org.luaj.vm2.lib.VarArgFunction.call(Unknown Source)
  at org.luaj.vm2.LuaClosure.execute(Unknown Source)
  at org.luaj.vm2.LuaClosure.call(Unknown Source)
  at com.javamon.console.Script.runFunction(Script.java:91)
  at com.javamon.console.Script.runFunction(Script.java:96)
  at com.javamon.console.ScriptPlayerCreate.run(ScriptPlayerCreate.java:39)
```

What bothers me is the very last line. `ScriptPlayerCreate` certainly exists -- *it's running the very script that produces the error!*

**Things I have tried:**

- Trying different versions of LuaJ
- Binding a different class within the `com.javamon` package (same problem)
- Updating my ADT/SDK plugins
- Cleaning/rebuilding the project within Eclipse
- "Starting Over" (creating a new LibGDX project using the GUI tool, and manually importing my source files)
- Checking `classes.dex` -- `ScriptPlayerCreate` is certainly there
- Testing on separate Android devices (Moto X and Incredible 2)

I would like to reiterate that I have successfully used LuaJ with Android for *several months* without incident. Additionally, I have not changed my scripting engine since my last (successful) Android deployment.

### UPDATE

After trying to revert to backup versions of my app and Eclipse, the problem persists -- even on another computer. **I am beginning to suspect that `luajava.bindClass()` does not know how to interpret the contents of `classes.dex`**, and is instead searching for actual class files.

When I attempted to recompile some backup versions, I noticed that the recompiled version almost always has a *smaller* `classes.dex` file than the backup. Perhaps something is wrong or has changed with Eclipse's/Android's compiler?

I tried manually inserting class files into the com/javamon/console/ folder within the APK, but of course that messes up the file integrity, and even after re-signing the app will not load. Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Reverting to LuaJ 2.0.1 solved the issue.

It appears that all versions of LuaJ above 2.0.1 have a different implementation of `LuajavaLib.class`. In the new implementation, only Java system libraries can be accessed through `luajava.bindClass()`, whereas in the older versions, `bindClass()` permits access to local application classes as well. All other script functions behave normally; **only `luajava.bindClass()` is affected.**

In the newer versions, if a class is not found in the Java system libraries, LuaJ apparently checks the local application directory. Because the Desktop project is a runnable *.jar and contains actual `class` files, the Desktop version of the game would have worked properly in any version of LuaJ. Contrastingly, Android bundles everything in a `classes.dex` file, which is not "searchable" in the file-path sense. Hence the `ClassNotFoundException`.

Lastly: I have been using LuaJ successfully for months, so what changed? Apparently, when I upgraded to 3.0 several months ago, **Eclipse never actually recognized the file change**. It was only when I refreshed and cleaned the project that Eclipse realized a new version of LuaJ was present. Because the main project in LibGDX is source-files only (assets are in `-android`), you almost never click "refresh". Thus, the LuaJ problem has been a time-bomb of sorts.

I plan on submitting a support ticket to the author so he can address this issue. Until he does, **I advise Android developers to stay with LuaJ 2.0.1!**

Answer (score 6):

I got a similar problem，and I'd fix it

LuaJavaLib.java:202

original
        return Class.forName(name, true, **ClassLoader.getSystemClassLoader**());

change to
        return Class.forName(name, true, **Thread.currentThread().getContextClassLoader**());

Answer (score 1):

Also you can fix it with your class Helper.

Create package: `org.luaj.vm2.lib.jse`
In this package create following class:

```
package org.luaj.vm2.lib.jse;

public class Helper {
    public static JavaClass forClass(Class c) {
        return JavaClass.forClass(c);
    }

    public Class<JavaClass> huskClass() {
        return JavaClass.class;
    }
}
```

Then create something like bridge class:

```
public class LuaBridge {
        public Varargs getClass(String clazzName) {
        try {
            Class clazz = Class.forName(clazzName);
            return Helper.forClass(clazz);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            Crashlytics.logException(e);
        }
        return null;
    }
}
```

And now when you run your script you can pass instance to your lua script:

```
_globals = JsePlatform.standardGlobals();
_bridge = new LuaBridge();
//...
    _globals.loadfile(scriptName)
            .call(CoerceJavaToLua.coerce(_bridge));
```

Inside your LUA script:

First line:

```
local luaBridge = ...
-- some code here...
UserManager = luaBridge:getClass("com.dexode.cree.ScriptPlayerCreate")
-- used like luajava.bindClass("com.dexode.cree.ScriptPlayerCreate")
```